# I am getting error: Page not found in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

My urls.py page like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('',views.index,name='index'),
  path('analyze/',views.analyze,name='analyze'),
  path('about/',views.about,name='about'),
  path('contact/',views.contact,name='contact'),
  
]
```

My views.py page looks like this

```
from django.http import HTTP Response
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def analyze(request):
    djtext=request.GET.get('text','default')
    removepunc=request.GET.get('removepunc','off')
    fullcaps=request.GET.get('fullcaps','off')
    spaceremover=request.GET.get('spaceremover','off')
    charcounter=request.GET.get('charcounter','off')
    wordcounter=request.GET.get('wordcounter','off')
    print(djtext)
    #analyzed=djtext
    
    if removepunc == 'on':
        punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
        analyzed=""
        for char in djtext:
            if char not in punctuations:
                analyzed=analyzed+char
        params={'purpose':'Remove punctuations','analyzed_text':analyzed}
        return render(request,'analyze.html',params)

    elif fullcaps=='on':
        # analyzed=djtext1
        analyzed=""
        for i in djtext:
            if i==" ":
                analyzed=analyzed+" "
            else:
                analyzed=analyzed+i.upper()
        params={'purpose':'Capital Letter First','analyzed_text':analyzed}
        return render(request,'analyze.html',params)
    
    elif spaceremover == 'on':
        analyzed=djtext.replace(" ","")
        params={'purpose':'Space Remover','analyzed_text':analyzed}
        return render(request,'analyze.html',params)

    elif charcounter == 'on':
        counter=0
        for char in djtext:
            if char==" ":
                continue
            else:
                counter=counter+1
        params={'purpose':'Character Counter','analyzed_text':counter}
        return render(request,'analyze.html',params)
    elif wordcounter == 'on':
        counter=1
        for char in djtext:
            if char==' ':
                counter=counter+1
        params={'purpose':'Word Counter','analyzed_text':counter}
        return render(request,'analyze.html',params)

    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")
    

def about(request):
    return render(request,'about.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

my index.html page-- Here I have shown only navbar part where error can be . My index.html page is in template/textutils and about and contact page are also in template/textutils.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/textutils/about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/textutils/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>

          </ul>
</div>
```

I am getting index.html page but I am not to get about.html page and contact.html page. I think my problem is either in urls.py or in index.html.

Comment: **/textutils/** is it neccessary in the .html files!

Comment: I don't think so.. I am just testing by adding `/textutils/ `.

Answer (score 1):

index.html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Finally I got the answer, It requires Jinja code in index.html and all code will be as same as previous. The only thing I have made changes is that in my index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is linking to `/textutils/about`

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/textutils/about">About Us</a>
```

However, it seems like your URLS are expecting only `about`. Removing the `textutils/` from the link should work, or add it to your `urls.py`. file

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it is also not working.